# Añadir valores a un dicicionario en java

Tags: java, diccionarios

Estoy intentando crear una funcion donde introduzco todas las posibles cartas de una baraja de poker. Al intentar hacer esto:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> makeDeck() {
        final String SUITS[] = {"spades", "hearts", "diamonds", "clubs"};
        final String  VALUES[] = {"AS", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
        
        HashMap<String, String> deck = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        for (String s: SUITS) {
            for (String v: VALUES) {
                System.out.println(s + v);
                deck.add(s, v);
            }
        }
        return deck;
        
    }
```

El resultado al imprimir *deck* es: `{diamonds=K, hearts=K, clubs=K, spades=K}`, cuando el deseado seria: `{diamonds=AS, diamonds=1, diamonds=2, diamonds=3...etc}`

Creo que es problema a la hora de hacer `deck.add(s, v);` pero no consigo arreglarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Por definicion en los mapas de *hash* `put` reemplaza el valor asociado al *key* establecido, lo que ves es eso, por cada *key* que ya exista se realizará el reemplazo de su valor, no habra *keys* repetidas bajo ninguna razon.

Desconozco la manera como necesitas implementar cada `String`, pero supongamos un escenario en donde se retornará una pila de naipes... lo unico por hacer es declarar una pila y almacenar:

```
private Stack<String> getDeck() {
  final String[] SUITS={"spades","hearts","diamonds","clubs"};
  final String[] VALUES={"AS","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
  Stack<String> deck=new Stack<>();

  for(String s:SUITS) {
    for(String v:VALUES) {
      deck.push(s+v);
    }
  }
  return deck;
}
```